# What is the most efficient way to mock a user flow in a RESTful application?

Tags: uml, user-experience, balsamiq

How can I communicate in a very simple and effective way the path the user takes through my application?

I'm currently working in a Ruby and Rails environment, so I tend to visualize my application in terms of RESTful URIs. So for example, if I want my users to sign up, I could match a new route called /users/new. The thing is, I would like to see beyond that specific action, and visualize how many pages or forms does it take to create an account and some business logic associated with the process in general. In other words, I'd like to see a mix of a workflow diagram and some implementation details (at an interface level).

I was thinking in showing mockup pictures wrapped in boxes, and relate them through arrows with their corresponding GET, POST, PUT, DELETE methods and URIs attached to them. I think it is a good idea, but I haven't seen examples yet that inspire me.

In your experience, what helps you see the big picture? Balsamiq mockups allow to define links and navigate through the app, but it doesn't help to conceptualize.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of using a mind-map?  You could try the free [**FreeMind**](http://freemind.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page)

If you stick with UML, you could consider an Activity diagram.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're on the right path. Showing different screens with possible combinations of users' transactions between them is a good technique. Basically you would be able to show user's flow through your application and stress out decisions a user will make on the way. 
The good example for it was presented here http://vimeo.com/43869717

This technique called Storyboarding. You should be able to find some examples. But the one I mentioned above is one of the best Storyboarding techniques. I use it all the time to show the big picture and present application workflow from user perspective to my team.